# Как уменьшить нагрузку и поедаемый траф?

Tags: ajax, чат

В общем, написал чат, все в нем работает прекрасно, правда трафик жрет дико - 1мб за 10 секунд, при создании пользовался аджаксом, около 3 аджакс функций на странице, обновляю их раз в 500 мс. Вопрос: трафик расходуется только на полученную от аджакса инфу или еще обращение к аджаксу тоже ест трафик? Как уменьшить потребляемый трафик?

Comment: А что передаёте? Каким форматом? Может у Вас много избыточной информации гуляет. Дайте больше данных.

Comment: Может человек получает весь список сообщений сразу? а не только новые. Или может у него такой чат активный, много людей пишут...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [WebSockets](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) вместо AJAX. Тогда вообще не нужно будет страницы по AJAX загружать.

Comment: хорошее решение - не используем ajax и траффик по нему будет равен нулю!

Answer (score 0):

поставь кэш zip на некоторые скрипты и базу и да если у тебя будет слишком много запросов в базу то твоя база просто расыпеться