# Нагрузка на серв малыми запросами

Tags: ajax, чат

В общем, пишется чат, проверка на новые сообщения производится через ajax с интервалом 500мс. Получается каждые 500 мс к бд идет запрос, сильно ли это "коцает" сервер, есть ли другие варианты проверки на новые записи в бд, помимо ajax.

Как держаться сайты с посещаемыми чатами? Например вконтакте.

Аналогичная проблема со статусом online.

Comment: 500 мс очень мало, увеличить лучше-бы

Comment: При такой конфигурации, надеюсь вы не апач использовать в качестве фронт-ент сервера будете ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вконтакте скорее всего сокеты, о которых вам гвоорили в вашем [прошлом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/276473/ajax-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84)
 а именно [WebSockets](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос смело можно разделить на два:

- сильно ли нагрузится веб-сервер, если каждый клиент будет стучать в него запросами каждые полсекунды?
- сильно ли нагрузится база данных, если каждые полсекунды нужно делать запрос для каждого клиента на наличие новых сообщений?

Ответ на оба вопроса - да. Зачем вам вообще РСУБД для хранения не структурированных, и, как я понимаю, вр**е**менных данных.

Посмотрите в сторону Redis PubSub, почитайте про long polling. Решение задачи очень сильно зависит от того, какие у вас инструменты. Я бы сделал Redis'ом, и отправлял бы данные по постоянному соединению, а на клиенте парсил бы полученный по AJAX'овому событию `onprogress` JSON.

Websockets не поддерживаются Android'ом, [вплоть до актуальных версий](http://caniuse.com/websockets), а преимущества его достаточно мнимы, кроме как то, что связь получается двусторонняя, что для вашей задачи не является обязательным.